# Should I still use Open Directory?

Tags: server.app, open-directory

I manage the IT systems for a small business with around 7 members of staff. They currently have a Mac running Server.app with Open Directory and the Home Folders are hosted on that Mac.

They have Mac Mini's that are joined to the network account server. Although this is working well, there has been a couple of instances where the Open Directory has become corrupt and it also seems the future of Open Directory is uncertain and Apple may not be supporting this set up for much longer.

My question is whether this is still the best set up and/or if anyone can suggest a better way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance,

Andy

Comment: Consider also asking this question on the [MacEnterprise mailing list](https://lists.psu.edu/archives/macenterprise.html). The list is active and is frequented by numerous experienced administrators who will share their experience and future gambles.